# ASP.NET MVC split into multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fubumvc

is it possible to have ASP.NET MVC areas in multiple projects? For example:

```
Admin area - MyProject.Admin project
Forum area - MyProject.Forum project
etc...
```

From what I header it's not possible out of the box, but is possible with Portable areas from MVCContrib. Is it possible to do that with FubuMVC?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to do that with FubuMVC?

FubuMVC allows you to package up controllers, views, assets, etc. by using Bottles (similar in concept to Areas, but better).

Comment: Can you give me an example of that or a link to documentation? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation is lacking, but getting better. Your best bet is to look at tests in the source at the moment and ping the group with any questions.

Comment: A good example of a self contained bottle is the FubuMVC.Diagnostics project.

Answer (score 2):

> From what I header it's not possible out of the box

You have heard correctly. The problem is with embedding the views into a separate assembly. While not possible out-of-the-box you could definitely achieve it as shown in [this article](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/).

> but is possible with Portable areas from MVCContrib

Yes.

> Is it possible to do that with FubuMVC?

I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a portable area setup that I wrote. You can package them very easily with MVC using the contrib. It isn't hard to do it.

http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/06/mvc-portable-areas/